# IntelliJ IDEA Sprig MVC Tomcat set up /conf file on mac

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

knowing this this is a long shot, but block for hours. any pointer is really appreciated. If understand correctly, IntelliJ IDEA and (Tomcat) compiled the project successfully.  however, while visiting localhost:8080 got this. 
there is my edit configuration. 
[image]

[image]

> /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.13/libexec/bin/catalina.sh run NOTE:
>   Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: 
>   --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED [2018-12-01 09:44:53,753] Artifact platform-framework:war exploded: Waiting for
>   server connection to start artifact deployment... 01-Dec-2018
>   21:44:55.624 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: 
>   Apache Tomcat/9.0.13 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.626 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:
>   Nov 2 2018 14:27:55 UTC 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.627 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:
>   9.0.13.0 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.628 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:
>   Mac OS X 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.629 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
>   10.14 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.629 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
>   x86_64 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.629 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
>   01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.629 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:
>   10.0.1+10 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.629 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
>   "Oracle Corporation" 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.629 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
>   /Users/davis/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2018.1/tomcat/Unnamed_platform_2
>   01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.629 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.13/libexec 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.634 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command
>   line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED 01-Dec-2018
>   21:44:55.634 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED 01-Dec-2018
>   21:44:55.634 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
>   01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.634 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/davis/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2018.1/tomcat/Unnamed_platform_2/conf/logging.properties
>   01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.634 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.634 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.634
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
>   01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.635 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 01-Dec-2018
>   21:44:55.635 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
>   01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.635 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 01-Dec-2018
>   21:44:55.635 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.635
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Command line argument:
>   -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.635 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
>   01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.635 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.636 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Dcatalina.base=/Users/davis/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2018.1/tomcat/Unnamed_platform_2
>   01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.636 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.13/libexec
>   01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.636 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.13/libexec/temp 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.636 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR
>   based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in
>   production environments was not found on the java.library.path:
>   [/Users/davis/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
>   01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.700 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8080"] 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.717 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read 01-Dec-2018 21:44:55.730 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"] 01-Dec-2018 21:44:56.264 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read 01-Dec-2018
>   21:44:56.266 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] 01-Dec-2018 21:44:56.268
>   INFO [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read 01-Dec-2018 21:44:56.269 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization
>   processed in 1220 ms 01-Dec-2018 21:44:56.321 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
>   service [Catalina] 01-Dec-2018 21:44:56.321 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13 01-Dec-2018 21:44:56.329 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8080"] 01-Dec-2018 21:44:56.341 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["https-jsse-nio-8443"] 01-Dec-2018 21:44:56.343 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"] 01-Dec-2018 21:44:56.345 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 76 ms
>   Connected to server [2018-12-01 09:44:56,681] Artifact
>   platform-framework:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please
>   wait... 01-Dec-2018 21:45:01.464 INFO [RMI TCP
>   Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars
>   At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable
>   debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were
>   scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during
>   scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 2018-12-01
>   21:45:01 712|
>   INFO|ContextLoader.java.initWebApplicationContext:304|Root
>   WebApplicationContext: initialization started 2018-12-01 21:45:01 779|
>   INFO|AbstractApplicationContext.java.prepareRefresh:582|Refreshing
>   Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Dec 01 21:45:01 PST
>   2018]; root of context hierarchy 2018-12-01 21:45:01 826|
>   INFO|XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java.loadBeanDefinitions:317|Loading XML
>   bean definitions from class path resource [spring-mvc.xml] 2018-12-01
>   21:45:01
>   828|ERROR|ContextLoader.java.initWebApplicationContext:350|Context
>   initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [spring-mvc.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   class path resource [spring-mvc.xml] cannot be opened because it does
>   not exist     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4643)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1737)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
>     at
>   java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
>     at
>   java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:457)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:406)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
>     at
>   java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
>     at
>   java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
>     at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:75)
>     at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
>     at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
>     at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
>     at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)   at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)    at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
>     at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
>     at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
>     at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
>     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring-mvc.xml]
>   cannot be opened because it does not exist    at
>   org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
>     ... 57 more 01-Dec-2018 21:45:01.832 SEVERE [RMI TCP
>   Connection(2)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more
>   listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
>   appropriate container log file 01-Dec-2018 21:45:01.836 SEVERE [RMI
>   TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context []
>   startup failed due to previous errors 2018-12-01 21:45:01 840|
>   INFO|AbstractApplicationContext.java.doClose:987|Closing Root
>   WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Dec 01 21:45:01 PST 2018];
>   root of context hierarchy 2018-12-01 21:45:01 854|
>   WARN|AbstractApplicationContext.java.doClose:1005|Exception thrown
>   from LifecycleProcessor on context close
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized -
>   call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root
>   WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Dec 01 21:45:01 PST 2018];
>   root of context hierarchy     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4690)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1737)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
>     at
>   java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
>     at
>   java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:457)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:406)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
>     at
>   java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
>     at
>   java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
>     at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:75)
>     at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
>     at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
>     at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
>     at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)   at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)    at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
>     at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
>     at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
>     at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
>     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [2018-12-01
>   09:45:01,872] Artifact platform-framework:war exploded: Error during
>   artifact deployment. See server log for details. 01-Dec-2018
>   21:45:06.337 INFO
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory
>   [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.13/libexec/webapps/manager] 01-Dec-2018
>   21:45:06.454 INFO
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory
>   [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.13/libexec/webapps/manager] has finished
>   in [113] ms

Comment: I thing the main problem is `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring-mvc.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist at `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the MVC configuration xml file as mentioned in the exception.

Comment: Hello Salar, could you add some information about this configuration file e.g. where they can get a sample file or how they could create one, and where it should be placed in their filesystem?

Comment: I think this might help. Pay attention to the configuration and the param passed to the context [link](https://hellokoding.com/spring-mvc-4-hello-world-example-with-xml-configuration-maven-and-jsp)